# JScript - Descobrindo o id da div anterior

Tags: javascript, html5

Boa tarde ! 
Preciso de uma ajuda para conseguir obter o valor da div anterior (vermelha `DIV01`)
Qual o comando posso usar para obter o resultado?? 
A Div anterior é o elemento pai certo? 
Desculpem a ignorância.

```js
function onClick(){}
```

```css
#DIV1{
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 background-color:red;
}

#DIV2{
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="DIV1"> 
 <div id="DIV2">
  <button onclick="onClick()"> teste </button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Que valor você precisa?

Comment: Da ID da `DIV01`, que consiga pegar a ID da div anterior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens várias maneiras,
podes ir por:

- `.parentElement.parentElement` (funciona mas vai quebrar se mudares a estrutura do DOM)
- usando tecnologia recente [`.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) (não suportada no IE) <sub>junto polyll da MDN em baixo</sub>.

Exemplo:

```js
function onClick(btn) {
  var maneiraA = btn.closest('#DIV1');
  var maneiraB = btn.parentElement.parentElement;

  console.log(maneiraA.id);
  console.log(maneiraB.id);
}
```

```css
#DIV1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

#DIV2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="DIV1">
  <div id="DIV2">
    <button onclick="onClick(this)"> teste </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Se usares o `.closest()` que acho a melhor opção, podes juntar isto para tornar compatível com browsers antigos:

```
if (window.Element && !Element.prototype.closest) {
    Element.prototype.closest = 
    function(s) {
        var matches = (this.document || this.ownerDocument).querySelectorAll(s),
            i,
            el = this;
        do {
            i = matches.length;
            while (--i >= 0 && matches.item(i) !== el) {};
        } while ((i < 0) && (el = el.parentElement)); 
        return el;
    };
}
```

Comment: O .parentElement ele vai retrocedendo de div em div e o closest vai diretamente na que eu preciso?
É mais ou menos isso??

Comment: Novamente muito obrigado @Sergio !! foi de grande ajuda

Comment: @Sora exato. Eu prefiro o `.closest()` mas usa o que te servir melhor. Repara que passei o `this` no HTML para a função receber o elemento clicado.

Answer (score 1):

Basta pegar o atributo `id` do `parentNode` da DIV2:

```js
//função executada no clique
function onClick(){
  //pega a div2
  var div2 = document.getElementById('DIV2');
  //pega o pai da div2
  var div1 = div2.parentNode;
  //escreve o id do pai da div 2
  console.log(div1.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="DIV1"> 
 <div id="DIV2">
  <button onclick="onClick()"> teste </button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, entendi !!! valeu pela explicação Artur